# How to repeat button click 10 times after click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to repeat a button click after the user clicks the button. I have found a `JavaScript` function that repeats the click. But I need the click to stop after lets say 10 times. The times should depend on what the user enters in a form (how many). I know I am asking for code... But I can't find anything good on the internet. I hope someone will help.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

The user fills in how many times he wants to hire a detective. The script will repeat the submit button that many times.

```js
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("send").click();
    }, 10);
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class="footer">Hire for (hours): </td>
    <td class="footer"><input type="number" value="1" onClick="this.select()" name="findtime" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="footer" colspan="2">A detective charges 2500 per hour</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="footer">How many: </td>
    <td class="footer"><input type="number" value="1" onClick="this.select()" name="howmany" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="footer" colspan="2">A detective charges 2500 per hour</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="footer"></td>
    <td class="footer"><input class="example_c" type="submit" id="send" name="send" onclick="myFunction()" value="Hire private detective"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) document.getElementById("send").click();`

Comment: Your design and approach is wrong. If you want to calculate the cost for the number of hours you need to do it by math not by fake clicks. If you are using a backend language like PHP or anything else then its just a multiplication. You can also calculate it with javascript the same way.

Comment: I am not trying to calculate. I am looking for a way that the script uses the variable from the input how many to repeat the submit button hire detective for that many times after clicked and than stop until clicked again.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  const timesToClick = document.getElementById('howmany').value;
  for (let i = 0; i < timesToClick; ++i) {
    document.getElementById('send').click();
    console.log('clicked');
  }  
}
```

Doc for `click()` function is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

Doc for setInterval (in you code) is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

In your code `setInterval()` would execute the `click()` function every 10 milliseconds.

`getElementByName` swapped with `getElementById` and `.value` added.

Comment: Thank you! i am trying your code but i am getting an error.. ncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

I am realy new to Javascript.. I now have tried to use your answer like this. 

`<script language ="javascript" >
function myFunction() { 
const timesToClick = document.getElementByName('howmany');
for (let i = 0; i < timesToClick; ++i) {
    document.getElementById('send').click();
} 
  

</script>`

Comment: @newusertomysqli12 post editted, forgot to add .value in the end to get the input value, notice to add ID to 'howmany' and name it the same. Check the clicks in the console, worked at my Chrome.

Comment: Calling "document.getElementById('send')" inside the loop is not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The code program shows that the code has an error when the "For" line begins. Is there a , or so missing?

Comment: Ok, it is loging click in the console times the value given in. It is not repeating the click that many times... No errors are showing in the console.

Comment: Help?? the click is not happening:(

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your script tag to

```html
<script language="javascript">
  function subFunction() {
    //do what you want to do in click here
    console.log("called");
  }

  function myFunction() {
    let num = document.getElementsByName("howmany")[0].value;
    while (num-- > 0) {
      subFunction();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Edit : I think firing click inside a click handler is not a good idea.That is why I separated the logic.

Comment: OP has said that they are new to SO, so please it'll be great to add comments about your logic.